# C PRGMING 101: Dice game Assignment that adds an extra turn when players roll a 6

Tags: c, arrays, function, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define FILENAME "dice_rdme.txt"

int main (void)
{
//prototypes

int dice(int sets);
void print_info(void);
int dicereadback(void);

//title

printf("Commence gamble, test your might \n");

int sets;
srand(time(0));

// user input dialogue 

printf("Enter the number of rolls to wager \n");
scanf("%i", &sets);

dice(sets);
dicereadback();
print_info();
return;
}

//general print info

void print_info (void)
{
    printf("\n student info \n");
    printf("class professor and ta \n ");
    printf("HOMEWORK ASSIGNMENT#6 DICE GAME 2.0 \n");
    return;
}

//generate games, parse outcome, store   

int dice (int sets)
{

FILE * dice_rdme;

int a, b;
int plyrsum = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
int d, f, dlrsum;
int c[sets], g[sets];
int plyrset = sets;
int dlrset = sets;

dice_rdme = fopen("dice_rdme.txt","w");

    for (a=0; a<plyrset; a++)
    {
         b = 1 + rand() %6;
         c[j] = b;
         plyrsum += c[j];
         fprintf(dice_rdme,"%i ", c[j]);
         ++j;

                   // if (b=6)
                   // a--;
    }

    if (a == plyrset)
    {
         fprintf(dice_rdme, "player score = %i \n", plyrsum);
    }

    for (d=0; d<dlrset; d++)
    {
         f = 1 + rand() %6;
         g[k] = f;
         dlrsum += g[k];
         fprintf(dice_rdme,"%i ", g[k]);    
         ++k;
                    // if (f=6)
                    //d--;
    }

    if (d == dlrset)
        fprintf(dice_rdme, " dealer score = %i \n", dlrsum);
    if (c>g)
        fprintf(dice_rdme, " \n You win! \n");
    if (g>c)
        fprintf(dice_rdme, " \n You lose\n ");

fclose(dice_rdme);
return(0);
}

//games are done, spit em back to stdout

int dicereadback(void)
{
FILE * dice_rdme;
char buff[1000];

dice_rdme = fopen("dice_rdme.txt","r");

    while(fgets(buff,1000,dice_rdme)!=NULL)
    printf("%s",buff);

fclose(dice_rdme);
return(0);      
}
```

Before I changed plyrsum to = 0 as a definition I experienced the following errors, I do not understand where these values are coming from. The player score seems to have defaulted or used like a placeholder or address as an integer(?grasping at straws?)

```
kettingstad@esc_151:~/workspace $ gcc HW6.c -lm -o hw6test.o
kettingstad@esc_151:~/workspace $ ./hw6test.o
Commence gamble, test your might 
Enter the number of rolls to wager 
3
6 2 4 player score = 32779 
4 6 3  dealer score = 13 

You lose, here are some pamphlets for gambling addiction treatment.... 

kettingstad@esc_151:~/workspace $ ./hw6test.o
Commence gamble, test your might 
Enter the number of rolls to wager 
3
4 3 5 player score = 32779 
2 1 4  dealer score = 7
```

Here I pre defined plyrsum as = 0, but I still couldn't sort out the problem of making my function add an extra roll every time a player rolls a 6. I tried using an if statement nested in each of the for loops where the outcomes are generated for each player but I kept winding up with 8 GB .txt files, and a hung program. The assignment called for a more sophisticated read back of the scores from the txt file but I made the existing function so I could test the function "int dice(int sets)"

```
kettingstad@esc_151:~/workspace $ gcc HW6.c -lm -o hw6test.o
kettingstad@esc_151:~/workspace $ ./hw6test.o
Commence gamble, test your might 
Enter the number of rolls to wager 
 6
 6 4 2 6 1 player score = 25 
 1 6 3 3 1 6  dealer score = 20 

You win!
```

`

Comment: Perhaps you could put some effort into formatting the posted code so the indentation isn't seemingly random.

Comment: Do you have a pet cat - as it seems to be sleeping on the space bar!

Comment: Hey man, you should see my professors' (yes plural) lecture notes. I hope this is more legible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Basically, you just want to set a flag if `6` occurs, save the current `sum`, roll-again, and then `take the higher of the two rolls`. One way to implement this would be:

```
int eroll = 0;          /* flag for extra roll (when b = 6)         */
int esum = 0;           /* extra sum (to keep greater of 2 rolls)   */

dice_rdme = fopen ("dice_rdme.txt", "w");

do {
    eroll = 0;                                      /* reset eroll      */
    for (a = 0; a < plyrset; a++) {
        b = 1 + rand () % 6;
        c[j] = b;
        plyrsum += c[j];
        fprintf (dice_rdme, "%i ", c[j]);
        ++j;
        if (b == 6) {
            eroll = 1;                              /* set eroll flag   */
        }
    }
    if (eroll) {
        esum = plyrsum;                             /* save plyrsum     */
        fprintf (dice_rdme, "EXTRA ROLL! current sum %i \n", plyrsum);
    }
    plyrsum = (plyrsum > esum) ? plyrsum : esum;    /* keep best roll   */
} while (eroll);
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/gameeroll
Commence gamble, test your might
Enter the number of rolls to wager
3
6 2 3 EXTRA ROLL! current sum 11
4 3 3 player score = 21
2 2 3  dealer score = 6

 You win!

 student info
class professor and ta
 HOMEWORK ASSIGNMENT#6 DICE GAME 2.0
```

**Note:** the extra `fprintf` is just inserted for testing.

As already noted, all of your equivalences `if (a = whatever)` need to be `if (a == whatever)`. You will need to verify the remainder of the logic in your code. C is an **exact** language, take your time and think about each line.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have already corrected assignment/is equal mismatch in my source. Have never used the do/while loop before, so this will be fun. Using sources like this for troubleshooting have been helpful in class almost exclusively because you extend my knowledge beyond the lecture.  The extra fprintf is actually probably going to go into my final draft, that will certainly make my output clearer.

Comment: Note, the above code block just replaces your `for (a = 0; a < plyrset; a++) { ... }` if you are wondering how it fits it. Just replace your code block with the above and recompile. The `do { ... } while (eroll);` is just a wrapper around your original with the additional logic. Add the new variables above `dice_rdme = fopen ("dice_rdme.txt", "w");`

Answer (score 0):

```
// I extracted the common dice roll/sum function for simplicity in the code
// I made use of the #define FILENAME rather than hardcoding the name in
// each call to fopen()
// I added checking of the returned values from the I/O functions
// I added #includes for the items I inserted into the code
// I moved the function prototypes to outside of an function body
// so the compiler will know the proper format of each function call
// at every function call, not just those within the main() function
// I set the return type to void for those functions those (possible)
// returned value is being ignored.
// I modified the format parameter for the call to scanf()
// to allow for any leading white space.
// I inserted the code to enable an additional dice roll when
// a 6 is rolled.


#include <stdio.h>  // for scanf(), printf(), etc.
//#include <string.h> // for memset()
#include <time.h>   // for time()
#include <errno.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILENAME "dice_rdme.txt"

//prototypes
void dice(int sets);
void print_info(void);
void dicereadback(void);
int  rollSet( int sets, FILE* fp );

int main (void)
{

    //title
    printf("Commence gamble, test your might \n");

    int sets = 0;
    srand(time(0)); // initialize random functions

    // user input dialogue
    printf("Enter the number of rolls to wager \n");
    if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &sets) )
    {
        perror( "scanf" );
        exit(0);
    }

    // implied else, read of roll count successful

    if( 0 >= sets )
    { // then invalid value entered
        printf( "ERROR: rolls must be greater than 0, exiting");
        exit(0);
    }

    dice(sets);
    dicereadback();
    print_info();
    return(0);
}

//general print info
void print_info (void)
{
    printf("\n student info \n");
    printf("class professor and ta \n ");
    printf("HOMEWORK ASSIGNMENT#6 DICE GAME 2.0 \n");
    return;
}

//generate games, parse outcome, store
void dice (int sets)
{
    int playerSum = 0; // sum of all player rolls
    int dealerSum = 0; // sum of all dealer rolls

    FILE * fp;
    if( NULL == (fp = fopen(FILENAME,"w")) )
    { // then, open failed
        perror("fopen for write");
        exit(0);
    }

    // implied else

    playerSum = rollSet( sets, fp );
    dealerSum = rollSet( sets, fp );

    fprintf(fp, " player score = %d \n", playerSum);
    fprintf(fp, " dealer score = %d \n", dealerSum);

    if (playerSum > dealerSum)
    {
        fprintf(fp, " \n You win! \n");
    }
    else if (playerSum < dealerSum)
    {
        fprintf(fp, " \n You lose\n ");
    }
    else
    { // tie
        fprintf(fp, " \n you tied \n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int rollSet( int sets, FILE* fp )
{
    int sum = 0;       // sum of all dice rolls
    int rollValue = 0; // value of individual dice roll
    int i = 0;         // loop counter

    // roll dice, if rollValue = 6, roll again
    for (i=0; i<sets; i++)
    {
         rollValue = 1 + rand() %6; // yields 1....6
         sum += rollValue;
         fprintf(fp,"%1d ", rollValue);

         if( 6 == rollValue )
         { // then allow another roll
             i--;
         }
    }
    return( sum );
}


//games are done, spit em back to stdout

void dicereadback(void)
{
    char buff[1000];

    FILE *fp;
    if( NULL == (fp = fopen(FILENAME,"r")) )
    { // then open failed
        perror( "fopen for read" );
        exit(0);
    }

    // implied else, open successful
    // note: fgets() appends a null terminator to the string
    //       so no need to pre-format the input buffer
    //memset( buff, '\0', sizeof buff);
    while( NULL != fgets(buff,1000,fp) )
    {
        printf("%s",buff);
        //memset( buff, '\0', sizeof buff);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This really fills in the blanks for me on several concepts. Thus far I have been performing very well without necessarily knowing what I was doing with every command, function, or technique.